# hibernate, How to load complex object in real world

Tags: hibernate

a real production scenario. background:  6 tables: Fund, Account, period, periodweight, holding, position.

```
Fund: The fund information, for example: fund name, total Asset, start time.. etc.
Account: each fund has an account (one to one) to fund.
period:  time period ( for example: 2000-01-01 to 2000-12-31)
periodweight: at a certain period, the target holding weight.
holding:  IBM, Oracle, GE are stock holdings.
position: IBM($3000), oracle($2000), GE($5000)
```

if I have a fund name:fake fund, which has a target holding for IBM (30%),Oracle(20%), GE(50%) for the period(2000-01-01 to 2000-12-31), the actural position for the 2000-01-01 is 10%,10%, %80% and on 2000-01-02 is 20%,20%,60% will be represents as these records in table

```
Account:  id  account_Number  Fund_id
         * 1         0001        10
           2         0002        11

Fund:     id        name                    other properties...
        * 10         fake fund                     xxx
          11         another fake one              xxx

period:   id        start_time        end_time    fund_id 
         * 3        2000-01-01        2000-12-31     10
           4        2001-01-01        2001-12-31     10

periodWeight:    id      target_weight     holding_id    period_id
                *11        30%                 21           3
                *12        20%                 22           3
                *13        50%                 23           3

holding:     id             name          order       other properties... 
            *21             IBM             1              xxx
            *22             Oracle          2              xxx
            *23             GE              3              xxx

position:      id      Account_id    holding_id    date             actual_position
               1          1         11         2000-01-01          10%
               2          1         12         2000-01-01          10%
               3          1         13         2000-01-01          80%
               4          1         11         2000-01-02          20%
               5          1         12         2000-01-02          20%
               6          1         13         2000-01-02          60%
```

The java Class are

```
Account{
    @onetoOne(mappedby="account")
    Fund f;

    @oneToMany
    Set<Position> positions;
}

Fund{
    @manyToOne
    Account account;

    @oneToMany(mappedby="fund")
    Set<Period> periods;
}

Period{
    @manyToOne
    Fund fund;

    @oneToMany(mappedby="period")
    Set<PeriodWeight> periodWeights;
}

PeriodWeight{
    @manyToOne
    Period period;

    @ManyToOne
    Holding holding
}

Holding{
    @OneToMany(mappedby="holding")
    Set<PeriodWeight> periodWeights;

    @OneToMany
    Set<Position> positions;
}

Position{
    @manyToOne
    Account account;

    @manyToOne
    Holding holding;
}
```

I want to have a query:
Based on the date (2000-01-01) and the fund name(fake fund). I want to build a Fund object, which contains the account and period(2000-01-01 to 2000-12-31), and period contains the periodWeight, and periodWeight contains holding, and holding contains postions for (2000-01-01). when there is no such position, for example, I query 2000-01-03 and fake fund, I want to have the structure, just the position is an empty set in the holding.

this hql can load the structure correctly if there is data.

```
select f from Fund f
inner join fetch f.account a
inner join fetch f.period p
inner join fetch p.periodWeight w
inner join fetch w.holding h
inner join fetch h.positions po
where f.name=:name and :date between p.start_date and p.end_date and :date=po.date and po.account= a
```

the problem is when there is no data at the position table for that day, it return null. I need a sql to give me the structure when there is no data, it can load everything except the position, just leave the position set empty.

another question is what is the better way to load such an complex structure? one hql like these or load part of the structure by one hql then other part by another hql? beause in sql, you alway load them one by one, first is the fund, then period, then weight,then holding, then position etc.. the weight need to be sort based on the holding order.

```
select f from Fund f
inner join fetch f.account a
inner join fetch f.period p
inner join fetch p.periodWeight w
inner join fetch w.holding h
left join fetch h.positions po with po.account= a and :date=po.date
where f.name=:name and :date between p.start_date and p.end_date
```

is something really close, but this give me error,

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: with-clause not allowed on fetched associations; use filters
```

Comment: "the problem is when there is no data, it return null" - No data where? in the positions association?

Comment: yes, when there is no data at posiion table for the date, I only have data for 2000-01-01 and 2000-01-02. when I query 2000-01-03 and "fake fund", it return empty list of fund.

Comment: I guess my first question would be, if I want to load such an object, should I break it to some mini steps instead of an ambitious loading everything at once? I just cannot feel the benefit of hibernate if I use too many mini steps.

Comment: Is this all being rendered on the screen at one time?

Comment: yes, one screen show everything, I think you might think I should not do the fetch at so many level. but if I don't, some of the mid level thing such as period will return me all the period if I say fund.getPeriods() and not only the matched one. any comments?

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do, breaking it into distinct queries won't help you here.  I generally try to formulate the simplest single query I can, and if that doesn't perform, reevaluate.  I'd also look at the caching potential for this data if its going to be queried often.

Answer (score 2):

This is annoying limitation in HQL, which I have come across a few times with time based associations.

I found that this is a solution to a HQL query containing `fetch` and `with` clauses:

```
select f from Fund f
inner join fetch f.account a
inner join fetch f.period p
inner join fetch p.periodWeight w
inner join fetch w.holding h
left join fetch h.positions po
where f.name=:name and :date between p.start_date and p.end_date
and (po is null or (po.account= a and :date=po.date))
```

The trick is to move the `with` clause to the `where` clause and add an option for the object to be null allowing it to return rows with out a position.

Comment: Unfortunately its not equivalent. You loose all those rows that are successfully join but do not match the condition in WHERE. See example http://pastebin.com/eY8Vw0xG

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this by changing:

```
inner join fetch h.positions p
```

to:

```
left join fetch h.positions p
```

and calling

```
query.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```

on your query object before you execute the query.

Comment: I am not quite sure what query.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY) is for. the left join not success. still null

Comment: Your query is using the p alias in two places: inner join fetch f.period p and inner join fetch h.positions p, you need to change one of them, then update the WHERE clause.

Comment: sorry,  it's a typo, I've change it in the question and put the right one. I also put a really close but not-there-yet solution. really wondering this one is worth such an complex hql? I totally agree with you to use the left join fetch, the problem is the with condition. it ask me to use filter and I am not sure how to use it. by the way, the position table is quite big, not applicable to load a lot first then filter, have to be fitlered on database query

Comment: and what is the common way to load object from database? i am thinking if I just load the object to the holding level, then if I do holding.getPositions(), it will return me all the dates positions. so I have to detach it? that's sounds contradict hibernate.